# getting column 'is_routed' cannot be null error. Even thought it is set to default=0 in database

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am inserting some values into database table using ORM.

Here is what I am doing:

```
placeorder_userorder=UserOrder(order_status='Processing',listing_id=all_response[0],actual_cost=total_original_prize,order_total=total_final_prize,total_without_dc=total_original_prize,
                               discount=total_final_discount,gst=all_response[0]['gst'], ,auto_invoice_index=0)

placeorder_userorder.save()
```

Model.py:

```
class UserOrder(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    auto_invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    auto_invoice_index = models.IntegerField()
    is_routed = models.IntegerField()
    ...
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_order'
```

Where `is_routed` is set to `0` as default (along with many other columns). Hence, I am not passing `is_routed` as an argument while created an instance of `UserOrder` as it is supposed to be `0` when new row is added.

[image]

But I am getting this error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: (1048, "Column 'is_routed' cannot be null")
```

Comment: post  `UserOrder` model's code

Comment: just edited, ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your model to this

```
class UserOrder(models.Model):
    order_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    auto_invoice_no = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    auto_invoice_index = models.IntegerField()
    is_routed = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    ...
    
    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'user_order'
```

Comment: there are 50+ column in table with default value set. Django orm is not picking up default value from Database itself. instead do i have to manually write for each default value in models?

Comment: yes, you have to add a default value to the models as long as you are using Django ORM.

Answer (score 2):

`is_routed` should be a boolean field.

This is how it is suppose to be -

`is_routed = models.BooleanField(default=False, blank=False, null=False)`

rest of the things look perfect to me. It must work now.

Comment: there are 50+ column in table with default value set. Django orm is not picking up default value from Database itself. instead do i have to manually write for each default value in models?

Comment: Yes, if you are using ORM manager methods to fire queries on your db table. If you are firing the insert query directly on db then it will consider the default value from your db table.